# How can a remote branch be local? (git-p4)

Tags: git, git-p4

When I use `git-p4 sync` to add additional p4 branches to a p4 repository I've created using `git-p4 clone`, they show up as remote branches, e.g. `remotes/p4/`*p4branchname*.  So they're not really "in" my local repo, meaning I can't push them, and I can't even check them out without entering the dreaded "detached HEAD" state.

But these branches *are* local to my machine.  So what does it mean for them to be "remote", and are there recommended steps to make them more normal so I can work with them?

Answer (score 2):

The way your local Git works for syncing with a remote Git is by maintaining mirror branches that reflect the remote Git (updated whenever you fetch, pull, or push). These are called *remote-tracking* branches, and their names start with the name of the remote, possibly preceded by the name `remotes`, and followed by a slash.

You are absolutely correct that they are "local" to your machine in the sense that they are *on* your machine. But they are not *local* branches. They do not belong to you, and you cannot (as you have rightly said) check them out, except in detached head mode as a way of studying them. Their only purpose is to maintain this synchronized mirrored reflection of the remote Git. And this makes sense, for safety. Git will never touch *your* branches, the *local* branches, based on the remote Git, unless you specifically ask it to (e.g. by merging or pulling a remote branch into a local branch).

The way to work with respect to a remote-tracking branch is to start a local branch from the remote-tracking branch. For example:

```
git switch -c p4branchname remotes/p4/p4branchname
```

That creates a local branch, starting at the remote-tracking branch, and checks it out so you can actually get work done. There are shortcuts for saying that kind of thing, but I recommend using the full version so that you know what you're doing.

Comment: Note that the convention that your local branch has the same base name as the corresponding remote-tracking branch is just a convention. But it sure is a good convention, and it makes sense to obey it, since otherwise you can confuse the heck out of yourself.